# Where has Numbers gone?

Tags: numbers

I created several spreadsheets in Numbers.  Lately I have been using Excel, which won't open them.  I can't find Numbers in my application folder--is it hiding somewhere??

Comment: Did. you search via Spotlight already? What does happen if you double-click on a Numbers spreadsheet?

Comment: It's [right here](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/numbers/id409203825?mt=12)

Answer (score 2):

It generally is located in your Application folder, though may also be in a folder entitled iWork within Applications.

You can try using Spotlight to find Numbers, if necessary...

Comment: The folder within Applications may also be called "iWork '09" or something like that.

Answer (score -1):

Apple has stopped including iWork as a part of the OS, and the apps can now be purchased separately through the APP store on your Mac. If you have purchased one of the iWork apps (Numbers) with your AppleID already, you can go into the Purchased section of the APP store and re-download the software. If you have updated your OS it is possible you had a version of iWork that is no longer supported (PowerPC).

Comment: Numbers and the entire iWork suite (Pages, Numbers, Keynote) are still included on rMBPs. See http://www.apple.com/macbook-pro/built-in-apps-retina/.